# Strange problem with pythontex in TeX Live on Mac

Tags: texlive, debugging

When I launch  `tlmgr update --self` in a terminal, I obtain the following error message :

```
Unknown docfile tag:  texmf-dist/doc/latex/pythontex/pythontex_quickstart.pdf
details=""Quick start" documentation" at
/usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 127, <TMP> line 129108.
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a typo escaping 'into the wild': see http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-September/034168.html. There are a couple of solutions given there: for me downloading teh [update script](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh), making it executable (`chmod u+x update-tlmgr-latest.sh`) and then running

```
sudo ./update-tlmgr-latest.sh
```

fixes the issue, as suggested on the mailing list.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know who has made this error appears ?

Comment: @projetmbc It was a combination of factors.